# Is there a list of all the woocommerce webhook actions?

Tags: woocommerce, webhooks

We'd like to hook into pretty much all of the data structures of WooCommerce via webhooks, but can't seem to determine what are all the appropriate actions. We've seen [the docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html) but if we simply pluck out all the "actions" we don't get everything we want (products / variants / orders being created / updated / deleted) and we do get a ton of stuff we don't care about (add to carts, etc)

Is there a better way of finding what the possible data-model oriented hooks are?

Answer (score 0):

No, these are custom events configured as a `do_action('some_action')` function in your site.

Then you have to set the webhook action to `some_action`, and make the actions you need in your site.

See [here](https://growdevelopment.com/woocommerce-webhooks/) for more info.